# Funcion de un prototype

Tags: javascript

Debo realizar el siguiente ejercicio:

```
function repetirCaracteres() {
  // Escribi una funcion llamada 'repeatCharacters' en el prototypo del objeto global String
  // que reciba como parametro un string
  // y devuelve un string en donde cada letra se repita una vez.
  // Por ej:
  // 'hola'.repeatCharacters() devuelve "hhoollaa"

  // Tu código aca:

  String.prototype.repeatCharacters() = function (string){

  var nuevoArreglo = []

  for (var i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {

  nuevoArreglo.push(string[i])

  nuevoArreglo.push(string[i])

  }

  return (nuevoArreglo.join(""))

  }

}
```

Mi funcion sirve ya que cumple con su proposito, pero no entiendo como debo hacer que funcione ya que de la manera anterior me arroja el siguiente error: Invalid left-hand side in assignment expression. (15:2)

nota: function repetirCaracteres() {} no la puedo modificar y debo trabajar dentro de ella.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Veamos los errores

- Es `String.prototype.repeatCharacters` =... NO `String.prototype.repeatCharacters()` (fijate en los parentesis)
- Es `String.prototype.repeatCharacters = function ()` NO `String.prototype.repeatCharacters = function (string)` Es sin el argumento `string`, porque el elemento está implícito en el prototype (ver punto siguiente)
- Dentro de la función ocupar `this` que será el string en cuestión

```js
String.prototype.repeatCharacters = function (){

  var nuevoArreglo = []

  for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) 
  {
     nuevoArreglo.push(this[i])
     nuevoArreglo.push(this[i])
  }

  return (nuevoArreglo.join(""))
}

console.log("hola".repeatCharacters());
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, nunca lo hubiera pensado asi, apenas voy adquiriendo la logica, muchas gracias otra vez por tu buen respuesta y por ilustrarme!

Comment: @SebastianOcampo De nada, fue un placer haber podido ayudarte un poco

Answer (score 3):

Tienes dos opciones, usar tu función `repetirCaracteres()` o `String.prototype.repeatCharacters`, no puedes utilizar los dos al mismo tiempo. Veamos el caso de utilizar tu función `repetirCaracteres()`, en este caso ya no vendría utilizar el `this`, sino el parámetro que reciba tu función (que será la cadena al quien queremos convertir), por ejemplo:

```js
function repetirCaracteres(string) {
  var nuevoArreglo = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
    nuevoArreglo.push(string[i]);
    nuevoArreglo.push(string[i]);
  }
  return (nuevoArreglo.join(""));
}

console.log(repetirCaracteres("hola"));
```

Y en el otro caso, tendría que ser `String.prototype.repeatCharacters` sin paréntesis, y tu código quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```js
String.prototype.repeatCharacters = function () {
  var nuevoArreglo = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
    nuevoArreglo.push(this[i]);
    nuevoArreglo.push(this[i]);
  }
  return (nuevoArreglo.join(""));
};

console.log("hola".repeatCharacters());
```