# No me funciona el método para duplicar caracteres dentro de String

Tags: javascript

Escribi una función llamada 'repeatCharacters()' en el prototipo del objeto global `String` que reciba como parámetro una cadena de caracteres y devuelva otra cedena.

Ejemplo (devuelve "hhoollaa"):

```
'hola'.repeatCharacters()
```

Código JavaScript:

```js
function repetirCaracteres() {
  String.prototype.repeatDbl = function(arg){
    return arg.split("").reduce((a,b)=>{ a.push(b+b); return a; },[]).join("");
  }
  return str.repearDbl(arguments[0]);
}
console.log('hola'.repeatCharacters());
```

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a la comunidad. Te invito a hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer [¿cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). ¿Puedes explicar qué es lo que falla o qué mensaje de error te da? Por ahora lo que veo es que no coincide el nombre de la función definida (`repeatDbl()`) con el nombre que esperas (`repeatCharacters()`).

Comment: Tienes el mismo error de [ésta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/584668/funcion-de-un-prototype).

Answer (score 1):

Cuando sobrecargas o creas un método nuevo de una clase, debes acceder a su contenido a través de `this` y no a través de un parámetro. De modo que el parámetro `arg` de tu método sobra, teniendo que reemplazarlo por `this`.

Además, estás creando una función normal y no creando el nuevo método en `String`.

Una forma de hacerlo correctamente sería la siguiente:

```js
String.prototype.repeatCharacters = function() {
  return this.split("").reduce(
    (acumulado, carácter) => {
      acumulado.push(carácter + carácter);
      return acumulado;
    },
    []
  ).join("");
}

console.log('hola'.repeatCharacters());
```

También:

```js
String.prototype.repeatCharacters = function() {
  return this.split("").reduce(
    (acumulado, carácter) => {
      return acumulado + carácter + carácter;
    }
  );
}

console.log('hola'.repeatCharacters());
```